# Persistant data of class data type

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, archive, persistent

I have a class instance of mine which is basically a mutable array of objects from another of my own classes. I need to store this in persistent data but I am having trouble, I tried archiving by using the methods

```
-(void)archiveFavorites {
    Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
    NSLog(@"archiving");
    GameDatabase *favoritesToArchive = singleton.favorites;
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:favoritesToArchive toFile:[self archivePath]];
}

-(NSString *)archivePath {
    NSString *docDir = 
    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Favorites.dat"];
}
```

in my view controller. I then call

```
[viewController archiveFavorites];
```

in my app delegate "app location did enter background"

basically I'm trying to store an instance of my own class (GameDatabase) in the archive. When it archives I am thrown the exception:

EDIT: Ok so heres what I am trying to implement now in my two classes:
GameDatabase.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:games forKey:@"Games"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        games = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Games"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

GameRecord.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Name"];
        self.gameRules = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"GameRules"];
        self.players = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"Players"];
        self.gameType = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"GameType"];
        self.drinkType = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"DrinkType"];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"Name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.gameRules forKey:@"GameRules"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.players forKey:@"Players"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.gameType forKey:@"GameType"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.drinkType forKey:@"DrinkType"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but you need to have your GameDatabase class implement the NSCoding protocol. Simply add the two methods [described in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Do I need to make it addhere to a protocol or just implement those two classes?

Comment: The two methods are the protocol. Unless you're asking a different question?

Comment: Wow all I did was add those two methods and it seemed to work but i didnt put any code in them. Is that correct?

Comment: By "working" it's true it won't throw an error, but it's not actually saving any data to disk. That part is up to you to implement. It sounds like you're still a little confused about how archiving works. Read the docs I linked, and the companion guide about archiving. It will answer your questions, I promise.

Comment: Ok I read through a lot of it and some more examples but I still have some more questions. Thank you for your help btw. I have two classes, GameDatbase and GameRecord. GameDatabase is an NSMutable Array with GameRecord's in it. GameRecords contains an 2 NSString's, and 3 NSInteger values (enum values). Basically what I am trying to archive is an instance of GameDatabase. Do I have to implement NSCoding protocols for both of them? I still keep getting tossed an exception.